# Non-deterministic Finite Automata - Epsilon Transition

Tags: math, computer-science, finite-automata

I'm wondering if Non-Deterministic Finite Automata can use an epsilon transition to reach an accepting state after computing all the given input? In a simple example where non-accepting state s1 has an arrow pointing at itself labelled 1 and an epsilon-labelled arrow pointing towards accepting state s2, given the input 111 would the automaton be able to process it like (s1,111)(s1,11)(s1,1)(s1,empty word)(s2,empty word) and thus accept the input?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: yes. If you can explain why you thoght that it couldn't then I can mybe write a more complete answer

Comment: In general, yes, there is no problem with that. However, there could be definitions that do not allow it. This might make some proofs easier, and not allowing it will not affect the computing power.